# Finding $\binom{999}{0}-\binom{999}{2}+\binom{999}{4}-\binom{999}{6}+\cdots +\binom{999}{996}-\binom{999}{998}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Find $$\binom{999}{0}-\binom{999}{2}+\binom{999}{4}-\binom{999}{6}+\cdots +\binom{999}{996}-\binom{999}{998}$$

A.$-2^{500}$
B.$-2^{499}$
C.$2^{500}$
D.$2^{499}$

By the way, I want to ask is there any command to type the combination sign(**C**)directly with (n,k)?

Comment: $\binom{999}{2}$ as an example to your second question (dollar, backslash, "binom{900}{2}", dollar).

Comment: `C^{n}_{k}` produces $C^{n}_{k}$ while `{ n \choose k}` and `\binom{n}{k}` produce ${ n \choose k}$ and $\binom{n}{k}$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

HINT :

We have
$$(1+i)^n=\binom n0+i\binom n1-\binom n2-i\binom n3+\binom n4+\cdots\tag1$$

Note here that $\binom n0-\binom n2+\binom n4-\cdots$ is the real part of $(1)$.

Comment: And consider that  $(1+i)^2=2 i$.