# Proving that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k\binom{4n}{2k}=(-4)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

I need sum this numerical serie. $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k \begin{pmatrix}4n\\2k\end{pmatrix}$

I know that the result will be $(-4)^n$ but i don't know how can I get it.

Could you help me with it please?

Comment: It is the real part of $(1+i)^{4n}$. see [a related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538252/finding-binom9990-binom9992-binom9994-binom9996-cdots-bi).

Answer (score 3):

**Basic approach.** There's probably an easier way to do this, but the way that comes to mind immediately is to use the binomial theorem on the expression

$$
(1+i)^{4n}+(1-i)^{4n}
$$

where $i = \sqrt{-1}$.  This will give you twice your summation.  Then observe that

$$
(1+i)^{4n} = \left[(1+i)^4\right]^n = (-4)^n
$$
$$
(1-i)^{4n} = \left[(1-i)^4\right]^n = (-4)^n
$$

and the sum of those two is clearly twice your desired value.  The factors of $2$ cancel out, and the formula is thus shown.

Comment: Thank you for comment, but it is definied just for Nanitonal and zero $\mathbb{N}_{0}$ I thought. I that ${n \choose k} = { n \choose n-k}$, but I don't know how can i solve this problem :)

Comment: In this form it is defined for *exponents* that are natural numbers, but the summands don't have to be natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \sum_{0 \le k \le 2n}(-1)^k \binom{4n}{2k} = \sum_{0 \le \frac{1}{2} k \le 2n} i^k\binom{4n}{k} = \sum_{0 \le k \le 4n}\binom{4n}{k}i^k = (1+i)^{4n} = [(1+i)^4]^n = (-1)^n 4^n. $

Comment: Thank you so much :). And it is not problem that we use just $0\leq\frac{1}{2}k\leq n$? because we have just Reals?

Comment: It's not a problem. Sub $j = 2k$ to see that it isn't. The upper bound is even, so it nicely cancels out; but if it wasn't, we would have floor expression at the upper bound.